# Play iframe video in full screen automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have an iframe like so:

```
<iframe width="100%"
        height="100%"
        src="~/Video/video.mp4"
        frameborder="0"
        allowfullscreen="true" webkitallowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true"></iframe>
```

I am running this on google chrome. Is there away with jquery or javascript to make this full screen when the video starts playing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Full screen" <iframe>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3982422/full-screen-iframe)

Comment: That solution did not work. This is a video iframe with a full screen button. I am just looking for away to it full screen automatically

Comment: What you have should work, per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14151899/when-using-video-js-why-doesnt-the-full-screen-button-work-inside-an-iframe.  but remember it won't upscale the video if the video is a small resolution, it will only be as large as the resolution of the video. (or are you expecting the **video player** to automatically go full screen??)

Comment: have u checked 2nd answer in @UncleRico mentioned link

Comment: I am expecting the video player to automatically go full screen